# Code in gridview_Rowcommand not updating control state (Eg. textbox text)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I am using a simple gridview which is as following:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="grdViewData" runat="server" Width="98%" DataKeyNames="RecordID"                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdViewData_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                onrowcommand="grdViewData_RowCommand">
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" 
    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" OnClientClick="window.scroll(0,0)" 
    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server"
 CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');" Text="Delete"                                                      CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns> </asp:GridView>
```

For updating the records in gridview i use gridview_SelectedIndexChanged method where as for deleting records i use gridview_RowCommand (if e.CommandName == "Delete") method as follows:

```
     protected void grdViewData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // Code Working properly Controls on page also getting updated

    }

protected void grdViewData_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            // Code to Delete Record (Working Properly, Record being deleted.)

    // Here Onwards code not working
     Message.Text = "Data Deleted Successfully..";
                ErrorMessage.Text = "";

        }

    }
```

In case of updating records, After updating I have some code to update controls on page which is working properly, but In case of deleting records, Records are being deleted but controls on page do not get updated. Attaching debugger shows that the code is executed perfectly but yet yet controls are not updated.

I have been googling for a day and really need to know the reason instead of going for alternative.

Comment: did you try rebinding the grid after delete?

Comment: Are you using updatePanels wrapping the grid? if yes you may need to call it's (update panel) update method.

Comment: Yes it is in UpdatePanel, But I would like to add that the same code in case of updating the record (Edit link button) is updating Textboxes, where as not updating in case of delete linkbutton